# SQL Server 2000 to Oracle 12c accented characters

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle

I'm transferring some text from a `TEXT` column in MS SQL Server 2000 to a `CLOB` column in Oracle 12c using java and jtds drivers (1.2.8).
The MSQL database charset is `Latin1_General_CI_AS` and also the text column is `Latin1_General_CI_AS.`
The Oracle database charset is `WE8ISO8859P15`.
The accented characters in Oracle become question marks.
I tried to debug the code and the text in java is showing correctly.
I tried putting `charset=ISO-8859-1` in the connection string, I tried putting -`Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1` before the java command, but nothing worked.
Have you got any idea? Thanks in advance
Edit: here's the code:

```
    Statement st = conn1.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from table1 where id = 63");
    while(rs.next()){
        String testo = rs.getString("TESTO");
        PreparedStatement ps = conn2.prepareStatement("insert into table2(id, testo) values(?,?)");
        ps.setString(1, rs.getString("ID"));
        ps.setString(2, testo);
        ps.executeQuery();
        ps.close();
    }
    st.close();
```

Edit2: I just tried to save "èèè" from SQL Developer and it shows question marks...never happened...man this is strange!

Edit3: From Toad it shows correctly...so it's a problem of reading CLOBs from Oracle 12c with java (1.8) whether I use SQL Developer (17.4) or I make a select from my code...I tried using ojdbc6-7-8 and including orai18n but still no luck

Edit4: if I use to_char the text shows correctly èèè

Comment: Show us the code.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Code added

Comment: Cooment to Edit4. Nice! Seems Oracle handles CLOBs a bit differently than normal VARCHAR2 text fields. Looks like you have solved your problem and you should now be able to answer your own question.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions179.htm

Comment: Uhmm not really because CLOBs can be bigger than varchar2...I don't know, this never happened to me, only with Oracle 12c

Comment: If you search for `convert clob to string java` you should find some suitable code samples.